# Manifest merger failed: Due to application@appComponentFactory

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this in my project:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-178:19 to override.

Then I added this particular line 
--tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"--
into my AndroidManifest file... But still i m getting issues...

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: Would you please share build.gradle file ?

Comment: To my ordinary gradle i added this particular dependency then i got this particular issue...      "implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217992/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-androidx

Answer (score 0):

Add this two lines in **gradle.properties** file and try again

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Added but not working... I added this new dependency then only i got this particular issue "implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'"