# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory - Androidx

Tags: android, android-manifest, androidx

When I'm building Gradle with `androidx` I get the following error. Please help me to solve this issue.

> Error Message: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.kanwarpreet.dealmybook">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.BookDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_book_details"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.AddBookActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kanwarpreet.dealmybook"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Try my solution. Remove all appcompat number verisons from gradle and imports from code, replace them with androidx equivalents and then sync gradle.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**After hours of struggling, I solved it by including the following within app/build.gradle:**

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Put these flags in your gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Changes in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

Refer to: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: compileOptions solved this for me after a day of Struggling

Comment: It worked but after adding these two lines in application tag of manifest i.e. tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx"

Comment: But there is a error in V7 imports in activity, what to do?

Comment: Thanks. The error was with this=`android.enableJetifier=true` is wasn't resent

Answer (score 109):

### Put these flags in your `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Answer (score 37):

### Reason of this error-

Because after upgrade, `androidx.core:core` is accessed somewhere, when your project is still not using androidx. So classes like `CoreComponentFactory` and many others are now found at two places - `androidx.core:core` and `com.android.support:support-compat`. That's why this error occured.

### What is solution?

You should migrate to AndroidX. If you don't know about AndroidX. Please read [**What is AndroidX**?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563)

### How to migrate your project

After Android Studio 3.2 (September 2018), there is direct option to migrate existing project to `AndroidX`. This refract all packages automatically.

**Before you migrate, it is strongly recommended to backup your project.**

> #### Existing project

- Android Studio > Refactor Menu > Migrate to AndroidX...
- It will analysis and will open Refractor window in bottom. Accept changes to be done.

[image]

> #### New project

Put these flags in your `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Check @[Library mappings for equal AndroidX package.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor)

Check @[Official page of Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor)

Answer (score 5):

Error explicitly says-

> [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0]

AndroidX is the latest support library from Google. It contains all previous components from [all older appcompat versions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx). **Do NOT use appcompat-v-any number**. Instead, use a similar component from AndroidX libraries. Remove the numbered support libraries from your Gradle and your code wherever it is imported. Then sync your gradle.

Component similarity table can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings). Also, follow the steps mentioned in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

**Again, stop using any previous appcompat numbered versions. There's only AndroidX now.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Remove the numbered support libraries from your Gradle and your code` not make sense because the `Migrate to AndroidX` is complete another process.

Comment: Op has mentioned "...when I building Gradle with androidx " When you use AndroidX one should use all of it otherwise there will be similarity conflicts with components existing in both packages support numbered ones and androidx. That's why I attached the similarity table.

Comment: @code4rox Just because it doesn't make sense to you. You can't downvote an answer. OP's error explicitly says "[com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] "

Comment: MD Naseem Ashraf u can clear see  in gradle the his project not completely converted to AndroidX so just enough `android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true`

Comment: @code4rox OP Just said setting jetifier and androidx to true did not help.

Answer (score 4):

you have to  move on the Androidx because your project is using some feature
from there.so you need to migrate to AndroidX
follow these snippets[image: click on the Refractor and then click on migrate to AndroidX]

look at this second snippet[image: make sure you have check on back project as zip file]

Comment: Don't follow this advice. I migrated to androidX but still same error comes out.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion to find out the exact reason is to open the manifest file and in bottom you will see a **Merge Manifest** option where you will see exact reason for failure.

See below image

[image]

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf as you can see I have added image too, other wise i would have added it in comment only

Comment: @Androidenthu. You can link the screen shot in your comment via imgur. I would suggest you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a line into **gradle.properties**

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Project-wide Gradle settings.
IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override* any settings specified in this file. For more details on how to configure your build environment visit http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process. The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode. This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

```
sec:decoupled_projectsvorg.gradle.parallel=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem because I was using some external library in my project and one of them was not converted into **AndroidX**.

Answer (score 0):

add below code to android/build.gradle under buildscript ext

```
googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
googlePlayServicesVisionVersion = "17.0.2"
```

and below code to gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I let Android Studio convert my `Relative layout` views to `Constraint layout`. So Android Studio added one of the `com.andriod.support...` while I added the `androidx...` dependency when I removed the second one the error was gone.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
}
```

This was my error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.3.2] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86
is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:3-26:17 to override.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:one.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

In manifest add tools:replace="android:theme" to your application

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve problem by removing

```
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
```

from app build.gradle and using

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

instead of it.