# How to fix ‘Attribute application@appComponentFactory androidx'

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

> Error:
>           Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>           is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>           Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-147:19 to override.

I don't want migrate to androidx but get this error when i add firebase in my dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0"
```

```
googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
    firebaseVersion = "17.0.0"

    compileSdkVersion = 26 // default: 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1" // default: "23.0.1"
    targetSdkVersion = 26 // default: 23
    supportLibVersion = "23.1.1" // default: 23.1.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory - Androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217992/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-androidx)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022157/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-cant-solve-th/57022608#57022608