# How to fix "error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist" problem?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I want to add an **Action Bar** to my app. And there is a problem appearing

`error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist`.

I cannot fix that problem whatever i tried. Any solution on internet does not work on me.I do not know why this is happening and i am really tired of it. I am the beginner and this problem drives me crazy.I've tried to change

`android.useAndroidX=true` --> to false

and

`android.enableJetifier=true` --> false on gradle.properties

Yeah, its work!But here is another problem appearing:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.1'
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
    androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'

}
```

Could be problem on implementation methods, i do not know. May be i have a problem on SDK versions. I have tried migrate to AndroidX and not worked.

Comment: your project using `androidx` as well as `support lib`

Comment: so Migrate to AndroidX

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx/55849025#55849025

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory - Androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217992/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-androidx)

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Welcome to stackoverflow!**

You have both **support library** and **androidx** library in one project...that's your issue...

Change the support libraries to the preferred AndroidX library...

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
    androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'

}
```

Or you can probably **Migrate to AndroidX** and it can be done right in Android Studio

Simply go to **Refactor** > **Migrate to AndroidX** > **Migrate**

Adding an Action Bar

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="@color/yourColor"/>
```

I hope this helps....

Comment: Yeahi thanks for help. But if i ask, why we cannot use both support libraries and AndroidX. Because i watch a tuttorial and they can import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: Then i suggest you use the support library instead of androidx

Comment: 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar' and 'androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar' do the same thing...the tutorial you're been taught on is just a bit old...but are you still having any issue?

Comment: Dave i am really pleasured for your help, really thanks! The last question is, how can i use only v7.widget? I just wonder it.

Comment: Well there's a way you could use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in your project..but you could have issues later in the future. Replace `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07` with `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` then go to your AndroidManifest.xml and add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"` just below your application tag...it should work

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing

```
android.support.v7.widget
```

with

```
androidx.appcompat.widget
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've tried but the problem still persist.