# Adding Google Play Services to an android app results in 'com.android.support and androidx.* conflict'

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

When I generate a new 'Empty Activity' app in Android Studio I get the following dependencies in app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

If I add

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
```

I get

```
Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support', myArtifactId='support-vector-drawable', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} and IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.loader', myArtifactId='loader', myVersion='1.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies more... (Ctrl+F1)
```

and

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

What changes should I make to prevent this conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is pretty self explanatory. It says:

```
Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined
```

that means, you're mixing up `support` and `androidx` dependencies.

To be more clear, you're using support libraries pretty much everywhere, i.e anything containing `com.android.support` in your `app/build.gradle`, but, the latest library for ads uses `Androidx` dependencies.

You can fix the error by converting your app dependencies to `androidx`, as the latest `play-services-ads` library uses Androidx dependencies, or, alternatively, you can use the older version of play-services-ads which used support dependencies (not recommended as support libraries are no longer maintained).

You can find how to migrate to `androidx` [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Regarding your another error regarding Manifest merger failed, you can fix it by following the instructions from the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217992/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-androidx).

Comment: Why does Android Studio generate the app with old `support` packages?

Comment: Apparently, looking at your build.gradle, yes.

Comment: Is there a way to generate a new app that uses `androidx.*`?

Comment: You can migrate the existing app without any error by following the instructions on the link provided. It's nothing serious, only the support dependencies stuff is changed to androidx. I migrated my production app with 10K+ active users without any errors.

Comment: Android Studio 3.5 generated the app with `androidx.*`

Answer (score 1):

From what I suspect, the version of play services you are trying to add is updated to work with AndroidX artifacts. You have 2 solutions to your problem:

1. Downgrade the play services library, however this is not recommended since play store usually requires the latest play service version.
2. Upgrade your application to androidX artifacts, witch is the way to go in such cases.