# implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2' (Firebase Auth UI) Give me Error

Tags: android, android-studio, implementation

When I add this dependencies :

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2'
```

it gives me the error.

I use windows 10 and android 3.5.

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2'

}
```

Error message:

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

See the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: it gives you suggestion can you try that?

Comment: @AsadAli Give me some hind. it will help me to try my best.

Comment: you can also try to comment implementation of app compat v7 and try, because this file is also present in another library and due to this conflict occur

Comment: its clearly said goto your manifest and in the application tag add this line->
tools:replace="appComponentFactory"

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: A simple solution will be just [Migrate to androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory - Androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217992/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-androidx)

Comment: @ADM I try it before and it give me much more complex error.

Comment: @SushenBiswas have you try to add the line in manifest?

Comment: @AsadAli in may manyfest file there is no :
tools:replace="appComponentFactory

Git Code :https://github.com/sushen/and-nd-firebase/blob/1.00-starting-point/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: you have to add this in your manifest

Comment: Where I am going to put this line.

Comment: inside the application tag of your manifest <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="appComponentFactory"
>

Comment: @AsadAli Now It through multiple Error :

Screenshot :https://snipboard.io/Q6JLxR.jpg

Comment: also add this line android:appComponentFactory="whateverString". if its not working you should try to migrate to androidX

Comment: Will you go with me for solving this problem. Now it give me more bigger error :
https://snipboard.io/T1bYmH.jpg

I try Android X before and It too much to handle.

Comment: @ADM I see you solve some Android x related issue can you help.

Comment: You have to migrate to **androidx**.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Can you join me in a hangout call. I can share my screen. I think it will take less time to solve this problem. I am totally stack.