# Build.gradle files corrupted

Tags: android, gradle

I have opened one of my projects after a month, and all the gradle scripts seems to have been affected. All the code of build.gradle files( both app and module level) is gone. 
I tried running the app on my phone ,it gave the following error [Manifest Merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217992/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-androidx), i tried the solution mentioned by Vishrut Mavani and app worked fine. But my question is what happened to all the code in build.gradle files. I had implemented many dependencies, if code is gone, how the app is still working?
I am posting the pictures of build.gradle files.
[image: build.gradle app level]

[image: build.gradle module level]

Other files in gradle scripts are also affected i think, but i am not sure. If anyone need the images, I will post them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

1. In your Gradle file, right-click, from the popup menu select **Local History > Show History**, from the **Old Changes** list, select an old change from a month ago, copy your code from there and paste into the Gradle file.
2. Android Studio > Build > Clean Project & Android Studio > Build > Rebuild Project
3. Android Studio > File > Invalidate Caches/Restarts...

Comment: Sorry, its not working. I think its a problem of apache license. I just saw that licence code has got access to src files as well. I installed apache tomcat during the period when i was not using the app. It seems the apache has got access to my app and posted some license criteria. Dont know what to do :(