# W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-server

I am trying to run the app that uses Anonymous login in the Parse server, but I get the Following in the log cat.

**The app runs on only one of my device with android oreo 8.1, but when tried it on other device with Android pie the log cat gives the.**

And this happens only with this app, other apps where I take the username and password from the user there also I get the same error.

I have tried all possible solution given to this problem on stackoverflow but the error doesn't goes.

Does anyone know is the Parse server which allows only one device to connect?

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter.uber">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DriverLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_location"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ViewRequestsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RiderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rider" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

StarterApplication file that connects to parse server

```
package com.parse.starter.uber;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("MY_APP_ID")
            .clientKey("MY_CLIENT_ID")
            .server("http://13.126.179.137:80/parse/")
            .build()
    );

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

  }
}
```

project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter.uber"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
}
```

log cat

```
2020-03-17 12:14:14.349 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
2020-03-17 12:14:14.353 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:292)
2020-03-17 12:14:14.353 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:146)
2020-03-17 12:14:14.353 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:140)
2020-03-17 12:14:14.354 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
2020-03-17 12:14:14.354 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-03-17 12:14:14.354 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-03-17 12:14:14.354 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-03-17 12:14:14.355 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to 13.126.179.137 not permitted by network security policy
.
.
.
.
.
2020-03-17 12:14:14.363 26020-26020/com.parse.starter.uber I/Info: Anonymous Login Failed
```

Comment: see *CLEARTEXT communication to 13.126.179.137 not permitted by network security policy*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Heading

[Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory - Androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217992/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-androidx)

**option 1 -**
Create file res/xml/network_security_config.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your URL(ex: 127.0.0.1)</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Option 2 -**
AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```